# get http body in go net/http

Tags: http, go

I wanna get http body data use go.
My demo:
[image]

I set `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in http request header, there is no error, but I can't get http body data.
Http Request Data like this:
[image]

I just wanna get the http body, I don't wanna use the method `request.FormValue`. What should I do?

Comment: The code you posted should work (it works for me). If it doesn't work for you, the error lies elsewhere in your program which you haven't posted. Please post a [mcve]. And don't post images of code, include the code as text in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke `ParseForm` before reading the form values

```
r.ParseForm()
for k, v := range r.Form {
    fmt.Println(k, v)
}
```

Comment: Kind of ignores the last part of the question, really: OP said he didn't want to use `r.FormValue`, which is basically the same as using `ParseForm`

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the request and get a response

```
    client := &http.Client{}

    resp, err := client.Do(r)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Client Error: %v", err)
            panic(err)
    }
```

Then get the body

```
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error reading body: %v", err)
                panic(err)
        }
```

Comment: unless i misread your question entirely.  I am guessing you want to make a http client request and then get the body from that request